# Python Matrix calculator GUI using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, matrix

Please, help me understand how to fix my code.
The `"="` button is not displaying in the `show_matrix_rank_page()` function.

Here is my code.

```
def matrix_rank_input():
    clear_frame(main_frame)

    Label(main_frame, text="Input number of rows and columns for Matrix:", font=("Times New Roman", 16), bg="#2F4F4F", fg="white").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
    Label(main_frame, text="Rows:", font=("Times New Roman", 12), bg="#2F4F4F", fg="white").grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
    rows_A = IntVar()
    Entry(main_frame, textvariable=rows_A, font=("Times New Roman", 12), bg="bisque", fg="black").grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)
    Label(main_frame, text="Columns:", font=("Times New Roman", 12), bg="#2F4F4F", fg="white").grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
    cols_A = IntVar()
    Entry(main_frame, textvariable=cols_A, font=("Times New Roman", 12), bg="bisque", fg="black").grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)

    # Используем partial, чтобы передать параметры в функцию show_matrix_rank_page
    Button(main_frame, text="Submit", command=lambda: show_matrix_rank_page(rows_A.get(), cols_A.get()), bg="tan1", fg="black").grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

def show_matrix_rank_page(rows_A, cols_A):

    clear_frame(main_frame)
    Label(main_frame, text=f"Matrix A:", font=("Times New Roman", 16), bg="#2F4F4F", fg="white").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=cols_A, pady=20)

    matrix_entries_A = []

    for i in range(rows_A):
        row_entries_A = []
        for j in range(cols_A):
            entry = Entry(main_frame, width=5, font=("Times New Roman", 12), bg="bisque", fg="black")
            entry.grid(row=i+1, column=j, padx=5, pady=5)
            row_entries_A.append(entry)
        matrix_entries_A.append(row_entries_A)

    Button(main_frame, text="=", command=lambda: matrix_rank(matrix_entries_A, rows_A, cols_A), bg="tan1", fg="black").grid(row=max(rows_A)+2, column=cols_A, columnspan=max(cols_A), pady=10)

def swap_rows(a,row1,row2):
    a[row2],a[row1]=a[row1],a[row2]
    return a

def row_transformation(a,x,row1,row2):
    for i in range(len(a[row2])):
        a[row2][i]+=a[row1][i]*x
        
    return a

def matrix_rank(matrix_entries_A, rows_A, cols_A):
    clear_frame(main_frame)

    matrix_A = [[int(entry.get()) for entry in row] for row in matrix_entries_A]

    ncol = len(matrix_A[0])
    nrow = len(matrix_A)
    rank = min(ncol, nrow)

    if nrow > ncol:
        # Транспонируем матрицу, если количество строк больше количества столбцов
        matrix_A = [[matrix_A[j][i] for j in range(nrow)] for i in range(ncol)]
        ncol, nrow = nrow, ncol

    for r in range(rank):
        if matrix_A[r][r] != 0:
            # Выполняем преобразование строк
            for j in range(r + 1, nrow):
                scalar = -(matrix_A[j][r] // matrix_A[r][r])
                matrix_A = row_transformation(matrix_A, scalar, r, j)
        else:
            count1 = True
            for k in range(r + 1, nrow):
                if matrix_A[k][r] != 0:
                    matrix_A = swap_rows(matrix_A, r, k)
                    count1 = False
                    break

            if count1:
                for i in range(nrow):
                    matrix_A[i][r], matrix_A[i][rank - 1] = matrix_A[i][rank - 1], matrix_A[i][r]
                nrow -= 1

    count2 = sum(1 for row in matrix_A if all(element == 0 for element in row))
    rank -= count2

    Label(main_frame, text=f"Rank of Matrix: {rank}", font=("Times New Roman", 16), bg="#2F4F4F", fg="white").grid(row=max(rows_A)+3, column=0, columnspan=cols_A, pady=10)
```

also, there's the error:

```
Button(main_frame, text="=", command=lambda: matrix_rank(matrix_entries_A, rows_A, cols_A), bg="tan1", fg="black").grid(row=max(rows_A)+2, column=0, columnspan=cols_A, pady=10)
```

I need the code to display the `"="` button and correctly calculate the matrix rank.

Comment: In the creation of the "=" Button, you have `column=cols_A, columnspan=max(cols_A)`.  I don't know what `cols_A` is exactly, but there's no reasonable type it could have where `cols_A` is usable as a `column=` value (implying that it's a number), yet `max(cols_A)` would be usable as a `columnspan=` value (implying that it's a sequence of numbers).

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.